# instagraapi returns wrong answer on my request, cant send request to instagram its returns error

Tags: python, instagram-api

i am trying send request to instagram by instagrapi after logining:

```
def parse_one_user(client: InstClient, user: str):

    try:
        print('one user parse started!')
        data = []
        print('user : ' + user)
        userid = client.get_user_id(user.strip())
        print(user + "userid")
        bio = client.get_bio(userid)
        print(bio)
        follows = client.get_follows(userid)
        print(follows)
        followers = client.get_followers(userid)
        print(followers)
        posts = client.get_posts(userid)
        print(posts)
        data.append(bio)
        data.append(follows)
        data.append(followers)
        data.append(posts)
        return data
    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        return False
```

i have this problem

```
    Status 200: JSONDecodeError in public_request (url=https://www.instagram.com/miami.autorent/?__a=1) >>> for (;;);{"__ar":1,"error":1357004,"errorSummary":"Sorry, something went wrong","errorDescription":"Please try closing and re-opening your browser window.","payload":null,"hsrp":{"hblp":{"consistency":{"rev":1005710968}}},"lid":"7110886975666527111"}
```

Does it means that instagrapi work wrong??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an error since it has a status code of 200.
Just a Warning from Instagram Directly.
Even if the error shows up in your Terminal it wont stop the script.
I have the same issues in my log files, but i doesn't interfer with your code.